# React showing blank space when same single character added two times to To-do List

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, web-frontend

So I have recently started learning React and as a project, I started making a To-do List. It was working fine until I noticed an error where if I gave a single character input twice, from the second time, it would show a blank space. I cannot understand why it is happening. Please help.

//App.jsx code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import Todos from "./Todos";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <h1>TODO</h1>
      </header>
      <Tasks />
    </>
  );
}

function Tasks() {
  let [task, setTask] = useState("");
  let [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  let p = items.map((i) => {
    return (
      <Todos {...i} key={crypto.randomUUID()} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
    );
  });

  function handleDelete(id) {
    let revised = items.filter((p) => {
      return p.id !== id;
    });
    setItems(revised);
    setTask("");
  }

  function clearList() {
    setTask("");
    setItems([]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="test">
      <form
        className="forms"
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setItems([...items, task]);
          setTask((prev) => {
            prev = "";
            return prev;
          });
          e.currentTarget.reset();
          console.log(items);
        }}
      >
        <input
          className="input-area"
          required
          type="text"
          name="text"
          id="text"
          placeholder="Create a new todo.."
          onChange={(e) => {
            setTask({ task: e.target.value, id: crypto.randomUUID() });
          }}
        />
      </form>
      <div className="to-do-items">
        {p}
        <div className="single-item task-count">
          <article className="tata">
            {p.length > 1 ? (
              <p>{p.length} items left</p>
            ) : (
              <p>{p.length} item left</p>
            )}
          </article>
          <article>
            <button onClick={clearList}>Clear All</button>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

//Todos.jsx code

```
import "./index.css";
import { CgClose } from "react-icons/cg";

export default function Todos({ task, id, handleDelete }) {
  return (
    <article className="single-item">
      <div className="task-area">{task}</div>
      <button
        className="cross"
        onClick={() => {
          handleDelete(id);
        }}
      >
        <CgClose size={25} style={{ color: "white" }} />
      </button>
    </article>
  );
}
```

I tried to set random keys for each child of the list but it is still not working, the blank space still is there. It's only happening foe single characters which are getting repeated, not for more than 1 character.

Comment: Ok i fixed it, in place of onChange i had to remove it and add onKeyDown and add if event.key === "Enter" then setTask. Glad i could fix it by myself. Thanks for coming to my ted talk. cheers!